# how to change text of button based on media query

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I want to change text "proceed to payment" to "Buy now", if media query is `767px`

```
const CheckoutButton = styled(GreenButton)
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: 'Poppins', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 40px ;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 6px 20px !important;
    margin-left: 100px;
```

`<CheckoutButton disabled={isSubmitting || disabled}  onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit">Proceed to Payment</CheckoutButton>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure CSS, you can add the button's label via a pseudo-element:

```css
.testbutton::before {
  content: 'buy now';
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .testbutton::before {
    content: 'proceed to payment';
  }
}
```

```html
<button class='testbutton'></button>
```

That being said, I'm not thrilled about having the button label in the CSS. In React, I always have a "uiStore" that allows components to keep track of the screen size and brakepoints, if they must. Then you could have something like:

```
const CheckoutButton = props => {
  const { layout } = uiStore
  return (
    <button>
      {layout === 'mobile' ? 'Buy now' : 'Proceed to payment'}
    </button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Possible Solution

Add/Remove inline text elements as per media query

## Solution

### React

`<CheckoutButton disabled={isSubmitting || disabled}  onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit"><span className="desktop-text">Proceed to Payment</span><span className="mobile-text"></span></CheckoutButton>`

### CSS

`.mobile-text {display: none;} @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.desktop-text {display: none;}.mobile-text {display: inline-block;}`